# Code is working problem is that the loop in card_elements is not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
url = "https://github.com/marketplace?category=project-management&type=actions"
driver.get(url)
```

## Parse the HTML content of the page

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
```

## Find specific elements using HTML tags and attributes

```
card_elements = soup.find_all("div", class_="d-md-flex flex-wrap mb-4")
```

## Extract the data from the elements but it only give 1 result

```
cards = []
for card_element in card_elements:
    title_element = card_element.find("h3", class_="h4")
    title = title_element.text
    description_element = card_element.find("p", class_="color-fg-muted lh-condensed wb-break-word mb-0")
    description = description_element.text
    #link = title_element["href"]
    card = {
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        #"link": link
    }
    cards.append(card)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for selenium and try to select your elements more specific - Use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for example and avoid use of classes, instead watch out for ids or HTML structure.

Main issue is, that there is only one element with classes you are searching   for, the container of all cards. So `ResultSet` is only iterated one time.

Instead select the `<a>` in that container taht contains a `<h3>`:

```
soup.select('a:has(h3)')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://github.com/marketplace?category=project-management&type=actions').text)
data = []
for e in soup.select('a:has(h3)'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.h3.text.strip(),
        'author':e.p.text.strip() if e.p else None ,
        'description':e.select_one('p:last-of-type').text.strip()
    })
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'Glo Add Assignee To Cards',
  'author': 'Axosoft',
  'description': 'GitHub action to add an assignee to Glo Boards cards'},
 {'title': 'Glo Move Cards',
  'author': 'Axosoft',
  'description': 'GitHub action to move Glo Boards cards to a column'},
 {'title': 'Jira Find issue key',
  'author': 'atlassian',
  'description': 'Find an issue inside event'},
 {'title': 'Jira Issue Transition',
  'author': 'atlassian',
  'description': 'Change status of specific Jira issue'},
 {'title': 'Jira issue from TODO',
  'author': 'atlassian',
  'description': 'Create Jira issue for TODO comments'},
 {'title': 'Jira Create issue',
  'author': 'atlassian',
  'description': 'Create a new Jira issue'},...]
```

Comment: when i tried to change the url to be scrape in the same website error will occur  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://github.com/marketplace?category=api-management&page=1&type=apps').text)`

Comment: If the structure changes or elements are not available you have to handle it, there is no one fits all solution for scraping, if you have specific needs - check the code edit